# Allow backspace in contenteditable in Service Console

Tags: javascript, service-cloud-console, html5

I cannot press backspace in a `<div contenteditable="true" />` in Service console.  I would like to.

The reason, as far as I can tell, is that in ServiceDeskViewCTI.js, there's the following line of JS:

```
Sfdc.on(document, "keydown", function(a) {
    var b = document.activeElement ? document.activeElement.tagName.toUpperCase() : !1;
    !("INPUT" === b || "TEXTAREA" === b) && 8 === a.keyCode && Sfdc.Event.preventDefault(a)
});
```

I think I have seen similar code elsewhere referencing the method `Sfdc.support.servicedesk.isInputFocused`, which similarly defines an input as `<input>` or `<textarea>`.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing up this question, I did discover an answer, but perhaps not the best.  I added the following to my code (I was already using jQuery):

```
  $('[contenteditable=true]').keydown(function (e) {
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });
```

This stops the event from propagating to the `document` where Salesforce binds the method that calls preventDefault.

Comment: I had similar issue when using https://formbuilder.online/ in my website and your fix worked! thank you.